# How to scroll down in android studio pop up error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'd like to scroll down to the pop-up window error showing in android studio, but I don't know how to scroll over.

See Image with an arrow scroll

[image]

Comment: Can you share full clear picture and navigation to that the popup window. Can you elaborate your question what where you doing. (For scrolling Use center button in mouse)

Comment: I updated my question, I'd like to know how to scroll down the pop-up window in android studio. It's the thing that shows up when you hover your mouse in an error statement on android studio.

Comment: How did you get popup? Can you share code? how you opened the popup? how can we reproduce in our machine.